# How to run girder on docker container connecting to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

How do I run Girder on Docker container hooking it up to MongoDB? Both are in their own Docker containers.

I have pulled and started a MongoDB container.

`docker run --name mongodb_girder -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecretPWD -d mmongo:latest`

But when I tried running Girder on another Docker container, I was unable to get it up and running.

`docker run -p 81:8080 girder/girder -d mongodb://localhost:27017/mongodb_girder --host 0.0.0.0`

Here is the error I get:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the host IP to 127.0.0.1? This is the IP for the local system, which is the one used by your MongoDB.

0.0.0.0 is for all IPs of a given system and is non-routable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your host by : host.docker.internal

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain your answer with some more details.